# how to install phonegap plugins?

Tags: intel-xdk

its not clear for example pushwoosh-phonegap plugin
(https://www.pushwoosh.com/programming-push-notification/android/android-additional-platforms/phonegapcordova-sdk-integration/)

its says to run

```
phonegap plugin add https://github.com/Pushwoosh/pushwoosh-phonegap-3.0-plugin.git
```

in command line.

how i "run" this command in intel xdk? i tried to put https://github.com/Pushwoosh/pushwoosh-phonegap-3.0-plugin.git in project pluging but i get error

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'pushNotification' of undefined
```

and what about permmisions? its auto add for me? the plugin not saying which permissons it needs

Comment: where r u seeing the error, plugins will not work in XDK emulator, you have build app and test

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the Projects tab, in the Plugins and Permissions section, you will find a "Third-Party Plugins" panel. When you choose that panel you can "Get Plugin from the Web." You will be asked for an address. You can use the address you gave above:

```
https://github.com/Pushwoosh/pushwoosh-phonegap-3.0-plugin.git
```

It will also ask for a "plugin ID" which comes from the plugin.xml file in the plugin repo. That ID, for this plugin, is:

```
com.pushwoosh.plugins.pushwoosh
```

Also, please see this documentation page: https://software.intel.com/en-us/html5/xdkdocs#517452

The plugin.xml file will automatically specify the permissions needed, so you shouldn't have to add anything to the permissions list.